Sum across columns of the same name (or "key") in polars dataframe
I have this code
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame({
    'id': ['CHECK.US1', 'CHECK.US2', 'CHECK.CA9'],
    'libor.M2': [99, 332, 934],
    'libor.Y5': [11, -10, 904],
    'estr.M2':  [99, 271, 741],
    'estr.Y3':  [-8, -24, 183],
    'estr.Y5':  [88, 771, 455]
})

which gives
┌───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id        ┆ libor.M2 ┆ libor.Y5 ┆ estr.M2 ┆ estr.Y3 ┆ estr.Y5 │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str       ┆ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ CHECK.US1 ┆ 99       ┆ 11       ┆ 99      ┆ -8      ┆ 88      │
│ CHECK.US2 ┆ 332      ┆ -10      ┆ 271     ┆ -24     ┆ 771     │
│ CHECK.CA9 ┆ 934      ┆ 904      ┆ 741     ┆ 183     ┆ 455     │
└───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

Now what I am trying to do is rename the columns to shorter names such as
┌───────────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id        ┆ M2   ┆ Y5   ┆ M2  ┆ Y3  ┆ Y5  │
│ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str       ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪══════╪══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
or
┌───────────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id        ┆ libor┆ libor┆ estr┆ estr┆ estr│
│ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str       ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪══════╪══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡

and then collapse (= sum) across the columns with the same name, so that I get e.g.
┌───────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ id        ┆ M2   ┆ Y5   ┆ Y3   │
│ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str       ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═══════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ CHECK.US1 ┆ 198  ┆ 99   ┆ -8   │
│ CHECK.US2 ┆ 603  ┆ 761  ┆ -24  │
│ CHECK.CA9 ┆ 1675 ┆ 1359 ┆ 183  │
└───────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

I tried renaming them first, but got polars.exceptions.DuplicateError: the name 'M2' is duplicate.
Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

edit: I also tried something like
rename_func = lambda col: col.split('.')[-1]
new_cols = set([rename_func(c) for c in df.columns])

df.with_columns([
  pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().map(rename_func) == c).alias(c) for c in new_cols
])

but it doesn't quite work.

Do you know the names are M2, Y5, Y3? Or are you trying to this "dynamically"? i.e. group matching columns by prefix (or suffix)?

I have a rename function such as rename_func = lambda col: col.split('.')[-1] which gives the new columns names. In this example the last bits (M2, Y5, Y3). For different use-cases I have different rename functions. This also means I could get the new column names as a list like new_cols = set([rename_func(c) for c in df.columns]), if that helps.

Yeah, like you can do M2 = pl.sum_horizontal("^.+M2$") if you can explictly name the columns.

If you had a column that caused a clash e.g. libor.id the current answers would "break". There must be some criteria for the columns you need to target? e.g. "Every column not named "id"" or "Every column that contains a period" or something?

You could build a dictionary of the columns to aggregate, then use pl.sum_horizontal:
cols = {}
for col in df.columns:
    suffix = col.split('.')[-1]
    cols.setdefault(suffix, []).append(col)
# {'id': ['id'], 'M2': ['libor.M2', 'estr.M2'],
#  'Y5': ['libor.Y5', 'estr.Y5'], 'Y3': ['estr.Y3']}

df.select([pl.sum_horizontal(pl.col(c) for c in l).alias(k)
           for k, l in cols.items()
          ])

Output:
┌───────────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ id        ┆ M2   ┆ Y5   ┆ Y3  │
│ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str       ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ CHECK.US1 ┆ 198  ┆ 99   ┆ -8  │
│ CHECK.US2 ┆ 603  ┆ 761  ┆ -24 │
│ CHECK.CA9 ┆ 1675 ┆ 1359 ┆ 183 │
└───────────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘


Also +1 for teaching me about setdefault.

would a defaultdict not be a better fit here? you avoid repeatedly calling setdefault

@sammywemmy sure, you could use a defaultdict but I don't expect it to be necessarily more efficient.

fair point. if the size is not large then sure. with the defaultdict the default is set once, compared to the approach you currently have where you set the default a couple of times. but you are right, premature optimization and all

@sammywemmy I compared d = {} ; for i in range(100_000): d.setdefault(i%100, []).append(i) and d = defaultdict(lambda : []); for i in range(100_00): d[i%100].append(i) and defaultdict is indeed a bit faster (7.94 ms ± 742 µs vs 5.88 ms ± 402 µs). Good to know :)

You can make your headings using set then use regex in pl.col to select those columns
headings = set([y[1] for x in df.columns if len(y:=x.split('.'))==2])
df.select('id',
    *[pl.sum_horizontal(pl.col(f"^.+?{y}$")).alias(y) for y in headings]
)

Alternatively, you could do an unpivot repivot like this
(
    df
    .unpivot(index='id')
    .with_columns(pl.col('variable').str.split('.').list.last())
    .pivot('variable', index='id', aggregate_function='sum')
)

The unpivot/pivot is most likely slower but for some data structures the first approach doesn't work.

for this, it'd be better to do the sum horizontally, with your first approach, since you are working on less number of rows, compared to unpivoting then computing the sum. you are right though there may be scenarios where flipping to long form is unavoidable/more performant
